# Finding ways of different arrangement of a specific word

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given INDEPENDENT,
find numbers of ways of different arrangement if

all three letters E are not next to each other i.e. two E’s can be together but not all the three E’s.

I had  tried the approach of using number of ways of arrangement without restriction - numbers of ways of arrangement if all E are consecutive and manage to get the answer. However I want to try another way which sum up the ways of arrangement for EE    E and E  E  E.This is what I have done:

for EE    E:
(9!*10P1)/(2!*3!*3!)

for E  E  E:
(8!*9P3)/(2!*3!*3!)

but the sum is not same as the answer (524160)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For the other way,

- All $E's$ apart: $\frac{8!}{3!2!}\binom93$
- A clump of $2 E's$ and a single $E:\frac{8!}{3!2!}*\binom92*2$
- Add up to get the same answer

[Note the $2$ multiplier at the end in the second case because the $EE$ clump and $E$ are different "letters"]

Comment: I understand your method since I have used it on other problems.  However, you should explain what the multinomial coefficient and binomial coefficient represent so that readers do not have to make inferences about your procedure.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I have not even whispered the word multinomial coefficient. At this stage, they would have learnt combinations, permutations and permutations where some letters are repeated, and OP has already solved the first part of the question. Further, I have been encouraging OP to clear  residual doubts, if any, but no response has forthcome.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know of, to avoid Inclusion-Exclusion, in the approach that you are taking, is to employ Stars and Bars theory, instead.

For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

---

$\underline{\text{EE E:}}$

First, you need a factor of $(2)$, since the EE could come before or after the (isolated) E.

Then, assuming that you have EE, and then E, the EE and E units create $3$ islands of letters.  These islands occur before the EE, between the EE and E, and after the E.

So, you have to identify the number of ways that the EE and E can occur, in the $11$ letter positions, so that they are not together.

This corresponds to the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = (11 - 3) = 8.$
- $x_1,x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $x_2 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$

The constraints on $x_1,x_3$ represent that the EE is allowed to begin the sequence of letters, and the E is allowed to end the sequence of letters.  The constraint on $x_2$ corresponds to requiring that there be at least one **other** letter between the EE and E.

From basic Stars and Bars theory, you use the change of variable, $y_2 = x_2 - 1,$ transforming the computation into the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + y_2 + x_3 = [(11 - 3) - 1] = 7.$
- $x_1,x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $y_2 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Per basic Stars and Bars theory, this problem has

$$\binom{7 + [3-1]}{3-1} = \binom{9}{2} = 36 ~~\text{solutions}.$$

Then, for each such solution, which corresponds to the satisfactory placement of the EE and E, you must also apply the scalar of

$$\frac{8!}{3! \times 2!} = 3360,$$

since that corresponds to the number of ways of placing the $8$ remaining letters (3 of which are N, 2 of which are D) in the $8$ remaining slots.

So, the partial sum, for this case is

$$2 \times 36 \times 3360 = 241920. $$

---

$\underline{\text{E E E:}}$

Here, the analysis is very similar to the previous section.

Four islands are created, so the computation will be 
$3360 \times ~$ the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 8.$
- $x_1,x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $x_2, x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$

The constraints on $x_2,x_3$ correspond to requiring that there be at least one **other** letter after the first E and after the second E.

Using the same change of variables technique, as in the previous section, the computation of the number of satisfying placements of the E's is transformed via  
$y_2 = x_2 - 1, y_3 = x_3 - 1.$

This transforms the computation into the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + y_2 + y_3 + x_4 = [(11 - 3) - 2] = 6.$
- $x_1,x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $y_2,y_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Per basic Stars and Bars theory, this problem has

$$\binom{6 + [4-1]}{4-1} = \binom{9}{3} = 84 ~~\text{solutions}.$$

So, the partial sum, for this case is

$$84 \times 3360 = 282240. $$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

So, the results of applying Stars and Bars theory is

$$241920 + 282240 = 524160. $$

Answer (score 0):

Another way I think you could go about this would be using subtraction.

The number of ways you can arrange INDEPENDENT minus the number of ways there are to put 3 E's in a row would get you the same answer.

**Step 1:** Number of ways to arrange INDEPENDENT = $\frac{11!}{3!\,3!\,2!}$ = $554400$

**Step 2:** Now, there are 9 placements for EEE, from EEE_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ to _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _EEE; apart from the E's, there are 8 other letters.

Thus, the total number of ways to get EEE = $9(\frac{8!}{3!\,2!})$ = $30240$

**Step 3:** Now, the final subtraction: $554400 - 30240 = 524160$ ways.

Comment: OP has already *solved* it the subtraction way, he wants to learn the *addition* way.

Comment: @trueblueanil, you're correct, I did not read OP's introduction thoroughly. My bad!